# How do I wire up a 3 wire electric motor?

Tags: motor, wire

I bought an old Dewalt bandsaw. It had this motor attaced:

[image]

I initially thought it was just missing a switch, but in fact it has no capacitor and all the wires coming out of the motor are unlabeled. No wiring diagram is present. There are four wires in total:
[image]

I have identified the wire on the right as earth.

Using a multimeter I determined that

Green / black had a resistance of 8 ohms

Green / brown had a resistance of 16 ohms

Brown / black had a resistance of 23 ohms

I have found a replacement capacitor and wired it up like this (blue is neutral and brown is live):

[image]

Will this work? I have not yet turned it on and thought I would check here before proceeding. In trying to do this have watched plenty of youtube videos on motors and looked at wiring diagrams but am finding it tricky to match theory to reality.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Will.

Comment: Purging the comments, no need to argue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick search for "dewalt dw3401 motor wire manual" yielded a [manual](https://docs.machineatlas.com/DeWalt+Bandsaw+Manual+DW+3401+3501.pdf). Wiring diagram on page 15 of pdf.

There are different variations shown. Your motor has a 1-phase symbol on the far left side of the nameplate, which is what you need. The diagrams with the 1-phase motor have the capacitor connected to brown and black.

This is consistent with your measurements, too, other than one of the wire colors supposed to be blue vs "dark green".

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out.  I have been looking for this manual for ages! I will swap the dark green and black wires.  Thanks again!